# Add position fixed for my div content and then hide() being disable

Tags: javascript

I'm currently making my div content as position fixed, but after that, when I clicking other dropdown menu item, the div content is not hiding, it seems like the position fixed make the hide() function disable?
How can I fixed this problem?

Comment: To help you, we need to see some relevant code. For instance, which `hide` function you use? How does the relevant CSS look like. etc.

Comment: Or try to change display to 'none'